# MPMusicPlayerController Track Length

Tags: ios, audio, mpmediaitem, mpmediaplayercontroller

Using an `MPMusicPlayerController` is there a way to query the tracks length?

Using .currentPlaybackTime I can figure out how far I am into the track but I have no way of knowing how long the track is.

My `[MPMediaItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL]` returns null for some tracks so using the AVAsset won't work for me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Easy just use

```
   NSNumber *duration=[item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration];
```